# How to deserialize xml using XStream in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, xstream

Im receiving this

```
<header><h1>001</h1><h2>002</h2></header>
```

my dispatcher looks like this

```
<bean id="annotatedMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.AnnotationXStreamMarshaller">
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
        <value>someClasses</value>
        <value>someClasses</value>
        <value>someClasses</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And here I try to use the unmarchal method from XstreamMarshaller and return the Object to cast

```
public static Object deserializeXml(String xml)  {


    StringReader sr =new StringReader(xml);
    StreamSource ss=new StreamSource(sr);

    Object o=null;
    try {

        o = xStreamMarshaller.unmarshal(ss);

    } catch (XmlMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return o;
}
```

The problem came when I realized that the unmarshal method marshals the given object to a given javax.xml.transform.Result and not a simple String as the fromXml method from XStream.

thanks to [THIS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/oxm.html) i figured out how to get a Result Object from a String, but not sure if is the best way to do it.

Comment: I don't see why you have to manually unmarshal objects.

Comment: Well since I have a annotatedMarshaller bean, i tough I can use its unmarchal method instead of of declaring an unmarshaller bean.

Comment: I mean, I guess why wouldn't you just have your service use your data objects and let spring handle all the marshaling/unmarshalling behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally agree with thought that spring should handle all marshaling/unmarshalling stuff.
Everything you need is to declare *XStreamMarshaller* as one of message converters. 
That can be achieved via *mvc:annotation* section:

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:message-converters>
      <!-- Your XStream converter. -->
  </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

or via *AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter*:

```
 <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <!-- Your XStream converter. -->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```